# Why array indexes are zero based in most programming languages?

Tags: arrays, indexing

C++, C#, C, D, Java,... are zero based.

Matlab is the only language I know that begin at 1.

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/110804/7043 (sadly, can't close as duplicate - moving it to programmers.SE and then closing it seems silly).

Comment: Matlab is not the only one. Fortran is a good example of 1 based indexing. I think that 0 based indexing is better for general programming, while 1 based indexing is more natural for mathematics.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays are zero based in c and c++ as the represent the offset from the beginning of the list of the item.

These two lines have identical result in c.

```
anArray[3] = 4;
*(anArray +3) = 4;
```

The first is the standard indexer the second takes the pointer adds three to id and then dereffrences it. Which is the same as the indexer.

Comment: It will add `3* sizeof(int)` assuming this is an `int` array. This is pointer arithmetic.

Comment: So it's because inner machine representation, not because human thinking and reasoning

Answer (score 2):

Well, consider Dijkstra's famous article, [Why numbering should start at zero](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html). He argues that numbering should start at 0 because it means that the valid indexes into an array can be described as `0 <= i < N`. This is clearly more appealing than `1 <= i < N + 1`, on an aesthetic level.

(One could ask, "why not say `0 < i <= N`", but he argues against that, too, again for aesthetic reasons.)

Comment: That argument falls a bit flat when you consider `1 <= i <= N` -- which is even more appealing on an aesthetic level, cause now even the relational operators match.  :)

Comment: @cHao: that's the worst option of all, because it means that if you subtract the two endpoints, you no longer get the length of the array. It's actually a cause of bugs in languages whose array slicing functions are inclusive at both ends.

Comment: Eh.  I typically prefer `(start, length)` myself.  You don't as often want "items X through X+N-1" or anything like that; you want "the N items starting at index X".  And with that, the length argument all but goes away; nearly every self-respecting language these days has arrays that know their length.

Comment: @cHao Arrays know their length, but slicing is still very useful and common. Perhaps even more common in languages where you don't have to worry about the memory management for the slice.

Answer (score 1):

I guess because arrays use pointer arithmetic to refer to some value. Basically arrays have contiguous memory and if you want to refer to 5th element (a[4]) then a + 4 * size of int is performed

Say if you start with 1 then to refer to 5th element you will have to do something like a + (5-1) * size of int

Answer (score 1):

Probably "C" got it because it is more efficient. To calculate address of item in 0-based array it is enough to multiple Index by ItemSize, for 1-based array you have to calculate (Index-1)*ItemSize. "C" and then "C++" where most popular languages, so new languages have to follow same rules, it helps to avoid mistakes for those who use C/C++.
But this question seems to be offtopic and i guess it will be closed by moderator.

P.S. In Delphi/Pascal strings are 1-based, but for arrays you have to provide range and so you can use what you like.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has mostly historical reasons, new languages just try to use the existing convention which programmers are familiar with.

Older languages from which this rule originated were close to the metal, and an index is really the distance from the starting element, hence `0` makes sense for the first element.

Answer (score -1):

Because there are 10 integers 0..9