# Use of str.length()-1 in case of swapping a letter of a word with each other

Tags: java, string

What is the difference between `str.length()` and `str.length()-1`???

I can't really understand what is the use of -1 while using Str.length().

I am using it for  exchanging the first letter of a word with the last letter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why array indexes are zero based in most programming languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283008/why-array-indexes-are-zero-based-in-most-programming-languages)

Comment: Can you perhaps post more of the surrounding code?

Comment: Context is everything, Java is `0` based, meaning that most counting/indices start from `0`, not 1, so why a `String` might be 5 characters long, it's last character is actually at index `4` and the start character is at index `0`

Comment: The use **where**?

Comment: Even though I am not a Java programmer, I would hazard a guess that the difference between `str.length()` and `str.length()-1` is 1.

Comment: @JohnColeman: In C++ it can be *very* different if the length is zero due to argument promotion and unsigned wrap-around. Nice ;-)

Comment: Strange question. Obviously one is less than the other. If you want to know why one would be used instead of the other, show us the use case.

Comment: @Bathsheba With C++ can't you get even more creative and override `-` in all sorts of weird ways?

Comment: Indeed but then you're simply writing pernicious code. `length() - 1` has bit many a programmer in the past; me included.

Comment: @Bathsheba Interesting. All languages have their pitfalls. I hadn't done enough C++ programming to encounter that danger, but it is good that you point it out in your answer (+1).

Answer (score 4):

Well, `str.length()` returns the length of the string, and `str.length() - 1` one less than that.

Since you can also view a string as an array of characters, and the index of the first character in a string is 0, then `str.length() - 1` is index of the final character in the string.

So in loops iterating over a string, you'll often see `<= str.length() - 1` as the condition check. Personally though I always use `< str.length()` as that doesn't get you in hot water in languages that use an *unsigned* type for the length.

Answer (score 0):

String is an object that allows you to manipulate every charon its content, those are zero index based, so lets say:

This string "HelloWorld!" has a length of 11(because it has 11 chars)
where char 0 is **'H'** you normally use `str.length() - 1` to manipulate the object considering the last element in the String

e.g. get the last element in "HelloWorld!" will be  much more easier by doing: 
`charAt(str.length() - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

string.length()-1 would typically be used to calculate the position of the last character in a string. Since arrays in java are 0-index, the position of each nth character is at n-1.